# The/a theatre/circus/gallery

Tags: articles

This explanation is from one of the previous discussions about using "the" before certain nouns. Does this explanation apply to "theatre", "art gallery", "circus", "zoo" and other similar institutions such as "opera houses" and "ballet" too?
My example:

"I went to a/the theatre/art gallery/circus/zoo/opera house/ballet."

This is the explanation from previous discussions:

"If it's obvious which museum you went to, e.g. you are somewhere with only one museum, or perhaps you work at a particular museum, then "the museum" would be okay. If you are in e.g. London, it would be odd to say "I went to the museum" because there are many museums - "a museum" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Don't put too much faith in that "explanation from previous discussions". In practice it's perfectly normal for native speakers to say *We went down the pub last night* even if "the" pub could be any one of several nearby. And it's the same with ***theatre*** and ***museum*** (but *not* with, say, ***restaurant***). Also note that ***ballet*** and ***opera*** aren't quite the same usage (because they refer to the ***show / event / production***, rather than the ***location*** where it takes place).

Comment: There are no hard-and-fast rules. I think I  mentioned before that, at least in British English, going  to **the theatre/cinema/circus** means going to see a play/film/performance. You go to **the pub** to have a drink with friends, but you go **out for a meal** (or some similar phrase) rather than to the restaurant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  But large cities may well have a dedicated opera house and possibly a theatre that specialises in ballet.

Comment: @KateBunting: That's perfectly possible, but regardless of whether there's just one or *multiple* opera venues in the vicinity, native speakers wouldn't normally say anything like *If you drive past **the opera** you can park in a side street*. Because in *that* context, what you're referring to is *only* the "location" - especially if you're only parking to go shopping, not to attend a performance at ***the opera house***. And that distinction is even stronger with ***the ballet***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Note that OP put **opera house** in her list. I agree about **ballet**.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, do I understand correctly "museum" can be used with the indefinite article if I am in a large city with lots of museums and say "I went to a museum". (I think someone even mentioned that in the previous thread) But with "theatre" "cinema" "circus" "ballet" and "opera" I use "the". I went to the theatre/cinema/circus /ballet/opera." Right?

Comment: Yes, assuming you went to watch a performance.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, and I don't need to add "house" to "opera" and "ballet", do I? "I went to  the opera."  "I went to the  ballet." (To watch a performance)  Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right (_ballet house_ isn't an expression anyway).

Comment: @Kate Bunting, One more question, if you please. In my previous question : "But with "theatre" "cinema" "circus" "ballet" and "opera" I use "the". I went to the theatre/cinema/circus /ballet/opera." Right?" You said that was correct. But  I didn't include "zoo" and "art gallery" in that list. Are they used in the say way with "the" to talk about watching a performance and going to see art? And instead of  " the opera" I can also use "the opera house". Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131558/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-antonia-a).